# Multiply an element by a number and insert using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm wondering if you can multiply an element using jQuery a number of times and insert it using .html()?

I am building my own slider which might help put things in context...

I am getting a number of times an element is used, which is stored in a `var` called `eachSlideCount`. So for example, this might output 10.

Then what I want to do is create a `<span></span>` for each of these (so 10 spans) and insert this into a div to generate a pager.

`$this.next('.project-slider-count').html('<span></span>')`

Is there anyway to muliply this span by the `eachSlideCount` number and then add to the `.project-slider-count` element?

I got this far... but clearly missing something...

```
var eachSlideCount = $this.find('.other-slides').length;
var eachSlideTotal = ($this.next('.project-slider-count').html('<span></span>')) * eachSlideCount;
$('.project-slider-count').html(eachSlideTotal);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplication can only be done on numbers. If you want to repeat something, write a loop:

```
var span = '';
for (var i = 0; i < eachSlideCount; i++) {
    span += '<span></span>';
}
$this.next('.projectslider-count').html(span);
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, you can execute a `for` loop.  For example, in the following:

```
var count = 10;
for (var i=0; i<count; i++) {
   // Code
}
```

The body of the loop would be executed 10 times.

In jQuery, you can append a new HTML element inside an existing element using the `append()` method.  For example, the following will add `<span>` elements in a loop:

```
var container = $("#container");
var count = 10;
for (var i=0; i<count; i++) {
   container.append("<span>");
}
```

This is illustrated in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kolban/sa8robqp/).